# collaps multiple rows with conditions

Tags: r, tidyverse

I would like to collapse multiples row conditions using `tidyverse` and here is my example

```
df <- data.frame(value = c(2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                 name1 = c("a", "a", "b", "b", 'c', "d", "e", NA, NA, NA),
                 name2 = c("x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "y", NA, NA, NA))
```

I would like to collapse rows saying that `name1` is the same associated with `name2` is the same, then those rows would be collapse into single row. Any suggestions for me?

My desired output like

```
value name1 name2
1      2     a     x
2      2     b     x
3      1     c     x
4      1     d     x
5      1     e     y
6      1  <NA>  <NA>
7      1  <NA>  <NA>
8     1  <NA>  <NA>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this helps

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    filter(!duplicated(across(everything()))|if_any(everything(), is.na))
```

-output

```
 value name1 name2
1     2     a     x
2     2     b     x
3     1     c     x
4     1     d     x
5     1     e     y
6     1  <NA>  <NA>
7     1  <NA>  <NA>
8     1  <NA>  <NA>
```

---

If it is based on selected number of columns

```
df %>%
    filter(!duplicated(across(c(name1, name2)))|if_any(c(name1, name2), is.na))
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
 df[!duplicated(df)|rowSums(is.na(df)) > 0,]
   value name1 name2
1      2     a     x
3      2     b     x
5      1     c     x
6      1     d     x
7      1     e     y
8      1  <NA>  <NA>
9      1  <NA>  <NA>
10     1  <NA>  <NA>
```

Comment: thank you. It answered my case. Btw, `:` means that from the name1 column to name2 column right, then what if I have several columns between two those columns. It doesnt affect to our result, but somehow is there any way instead of using `:`.

Comment: @Anh I changed from `name1:name2` to `everything()` to include all the columns.  Please check my update

Comment: I think the code before u editted is better for my case, since I also have several columns between 2 conditonal columns that ar different

Comment: @Anh I added back the earlier version

Comment: thank you again. Another lesson today

Answer (score 2):

Here is an `dplyr` alternative using a `helper` column to prepare to apply `distinct()`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(helper = paste0(name1, name2),
         helper = ifelse(is.na(name1) | is.na(name2), 
                         paste0(helper, row_number()), helper)
         ) %>% 
  distinct(helper, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  select(-helper)
```

Outcome:

```
  value name1 name2
1     2     a     x
2     2     b     x
3     1     c     x
4     1     d     x
5     1     e     y
6     1  <NA>  <NA>
7     1  <NA>  <NA>
8     1  <NA>  <NA>
```

Comment: I learnt alot from this thing!

Answer (score 1):

Another tidyverse option could look as follows.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(if_any(name1:name2, ~ !is.na(.))) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  bind_rows(filter(df, if_any(name1:name2, is.na)))

#   value name1 name2
# 1     2     a     x
# 2     2     b     x
# 3     1     c     x
# 4     1     d     x
# 5     1     e     y
# 6     1  <NA>  <NA>
# 7     1  <NA>  <NA>
# 8     1  <NA>  <NA>
```